# Celery server error: “cannot mix new setting names with old setting names”

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery server with redis as a broker and flask.

After the flask server is running, I start the celery worker (by `celery -E -A app.celery worker`) but get the following error:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-115:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\objects.py
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'default_modules'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\objects.py
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\billiard\process.py",
    self.run()       [.....]
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\app\utils.py",
    for key in sorted(really_left)
celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:

Cannot mix new setting names with old setting names, please
rename the following settings to use the old format:

include                              -> CELERY_INCLUDE

Or change all of the settings to use the new format :)
```

But I am not using the setting name `include` or `CELERY_INCLUDE` ...

```
celery = Celery(
    imports=app.import_name,
    result_backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
    broker_url=app.config['BROKER_URL']
)
```

Where this error can come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do as suggested by http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/ 
Make shure to remove `celery.conf.update(app.config)` in the function `make_celery(app)`.
The error won't be displayed anymore.

Answer (score 7):

This error araises when you update celery configurations using 2 ways like

1.

`celery.conf.update()`

and

2.

`celery.conf.task_routes = {
'taskname': {'queue': 'celery'}
}`

Follow only one way

best practice is to keep all configuration in *celeryconfig.py* file and import in celery app

sample *celeryconfig.py*

```
broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
enable_utc = True
```

*app.py*

```
import celeryconfig

celery = Celery()
celery.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
```

Hope this solves your problem

checkout new lowercase settings [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings) to write configurations in new format